# Dismiss ModalView does not work here

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

So I have a tabBarController as a modalview, and it shows up fine. As I click some of the tabs, the views are loading properly. I want to dismiss the modalView when I click on `tabBarController.selectedIndex ==4`

So I write in the `viewDidLoad` and also tried in the `viewWillAppear` of that view controller to `dismissModalViewController` and it does not work.

I tried

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

      // ... And also //

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Could someone point out why it does not work ?

Comment: Did you present the tabBarController as the modal view controller, or the view controller you're trying to dismiss it from?

Comment: I presented the tabBarController as the modalViewController, and I want to dismiss it in one of the tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is pass a reference to the modally presented VC pointing on the VC that will present it modally.

Define a weak reference as a property in the UITabBarController subclass, and send a message to dismiss it when required.

For example using a property named `mainViewController` :

```
MySubclass *tbController = [[MySubclass ....];
tbController.mainViewController = self;
[self presentModalViewController:tbController animated:YES];
```

Then in MySubclass define

```
@property(assign) UIViewController *mainViewController;
```

and synthesize it, then when the tab you want gets selected :

```
[self.mainViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: This didn't work. Nevermind. I dismissed it with NSNotifications.. FML !  +1 Anyway.

Comment: @Legolas - I do that almost every day ;) think you have missed something while implementing this solution

Comment: What does this mean ? `tbController.mainViewController = self;` ?

Comment: @Legolas - this means you set a property you have defined in your tab bar controller subclass to `self`, which is the VC that present the other modally. Once you do that, you will be able to send messages to that VC from inside your tab bar controller subclass, espacially in this case to make it dismiss the VC presented modally.

Comment: I did this. - I get a warning message `incompatible pointer types` .. :O ?

Comment: @Legolas - isn't `self` in your case a UIVIewController subclass. Try to quiet the warning by hard typing the property ?

Comment: It is a subclass of UIViewController. But yes, I get your idea now. Seems logical. Let me try that out.

Comment: It seems to be posting an error. Since notifications helped me fix this, I am moving on to the next task right now. I will definitely find out about this technique probably tomorrow when I am free...

Answer (score 1):

I think the 4th view controller (of the tab bar controller) is trying to get dismissed by the line

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Since this 4th view controller was not presented by any controller, this wont work.

And it is dismissing it's modal view controller by the line

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Since, this 4th view controller did not presented any view controller, this again should not work.

You want to dismiss the tab bar controller and not its 4th view controller.

Basically, you can get the reference of tab bar controller from the 4th view controller.
As, `[yourFourthViewController.tabBarController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

I am guessing this without actually trying. Let me know if this works.

Comment: I dismissed it with Notifications. +1 for the your help anyway.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the UINavigationController as the parent controller then the following line will work for you.

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

But here I think you have the UIViewController is the parent controller instead of the UINavigationController. So, You can do one thing when presentModalViewController.

```
if(objView == nil)
    objView = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objView];

[self presentModalViewController:navigationController1 animated:YES];
```

Let me know if you need more help or any questions.

Comment: `If you have the UINavigationController as the parent controller then the following line will work for you.

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`... IS IT SO ! ?